# Is it possible to mount host machine folder when run process in docker container on the remote machine

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, cypress

I'm trying to launch my cypress tests on a remote machine with docker. So from host I do:

```
docker -H ssh://me@host run -v /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/TEST:/e2e -w /e2e --entrypoint=npm cypress/included:5.2.0 run test
```

The container on remote machine starting well, but then I get such errors:

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /e2e/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/e2e/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The folder from host wasn't mounted into container on remote machine.
Could you please advise, is it possible to mount in such configuration? And if so - how to do that correctly?
Thanks!